# how to call an array of keys from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

If I have the following array

```
someArray = [{id: 1, coordinates: {latitude: 1212, longitude: 13324}},{id: 2, coordinates: {latitude: 1314, longitude: 15151}}]
```

is there anyway to call `someArray` so I get just the array of the coordinates keys without having to make a new array? someArray.coordinates gives me undefined.
Expected output:

```
[{latitude: 1212, longitude: 13324}, {latitude: 1314, longitude: 15151}]
```

Comment: Arrays (as distinguished from objects) are accessed by numeric indices, not strings.

Comment: Give that array of objects, what output do you expect to get? A list of keys within the `coordinates` objects of each object? Or an array of coordinates from the those objects?

Comment: If you're answering my comment, please [edit] your question to add the expected output there, where hopefully people will be more likely to see it.

Comment: @MattBall Not exactly accurate. It’s all strings. Numbers are just converted to strings, but they will still be strings.

Comment: Just so you understand some of the confusion, you said you want to get "keys" when in fact you want to place the *"value"* of each `coordinates` key into a new Array.

Comment: so then how would I make the array index by my desired string?

Comment: @Xufox: I imagine Matt meant *"...not arbitrary strings"* in contrast to the *"...numeric indices"* he mentioned.

Comment: This problem has two parts. One is iterating (looping) over the elements of `someArray`. For that, you can use a loop. The second, is accessing the value of `coordinates` from each element. For that, you can use `elt.coordinates`. Which of these parts exactly were you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.map), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) for that:

```
someArray = someArray.map(function(entry) {
    return entry.coordinates;
});
```

`Array#map` produces a new array from the entries you return from the iteration function you pass into it.

**Live Example**:

```js
var someArray = [{id: 1, coordinates: {latitude: 1212, longitude: 13324 }}, {id: 2, coordinates: {latitude: 1314,longitude: 15151}}];
snippet.log("Before:");
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(someArray));
someArray = someArray.map(function(entry) {
    return entry.coordinates;
});
snippet.log("After:");
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(someArray));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: The expected output that he added to the question makes a little more sense than the comment. I think that's what he's after.

Comment: @squint: LOL, thanks -- my **first** answer did that! But then I realized I hadn't done what he asked. :-) Will revert.

Comment: Darn it, can't just revert, have to retype (was within the window).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But not really _retype_, right? You can just copy the [source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/87afd9e0-969a-4f57-9567-78e1db6094c0/view-source) of the first revision.

Comment: @Xufox: No, really retype -- the one I'm talking about was *before* that one. I realized I'd not produced what he said in the comment (but amusingly, had produced what he actually wanted) and edited, and it became a ninja edit. So it's gone now.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with a map function:

```
someArray.map(function(current, index, array){ array[index] = current.coordinates});
```

This will, though, modify your original. You can get it as another array like:

```
var coordinates = [];
someArray.map(function(current){coordinates.push(current.coordinates)});
```

And yes, sorry, I forgot, the easiest is:

```
var coordinates = someArray.map(function(current) { return current.coordinates; });
```

Or you can write it yourself:

```
function getCoordinates(objectArray) {
   var coordinates = [];
   for (var i in objectArray) {
      var current = objectArray[i];
      coordinates.push(current.coordinates);
   }
}

var onlyCoordinates = getCoordinates(someArray);
```

Comment: You're not quite understanding how to use `.map()`. Your approach would make more sense with `.forEach()`. With `.map()`, you *return* a value from the callback, and at the end, `.map()` returns a new array with those values.

Answer (score -3):

EDITED: Just use following snippet

```js
var someArray = [{id: 1, coordinates: {latitude: 1212, longitude: 13324}},{id: 2, coordinates: {latitude: 1314, longitude: 15151}}];

var i = -1;
while(someArray[++i]){
   someArray[i] = someArray[i].coordinates;
}

document.write("<pre>"+JSON.stringify(someArray,0,3)+"</pre>");
```

Comment: That isn't what he wanted. And even if it was, I don't know why you'd do it that way when you could just create a function that loops over the original Array. You could also use (and shim) the ECMAScript 6 `Array.prototype.find()`

Comment: yeah, he wanted without new array. but, how can find item if id is differently `someArray=[{id:4, coordinates:{}}, {id:9, coorditanes:{}}]` through `map()`. there is just `indexOf()` in my answer(i have updated again).

Comment: Also, `Array.prototype.find()` uses just  loop(`for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {`)  in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: In my experience, many errors happened with `null, undefind, [], ""` and pushing array (`isEmpty` and `pushArray` fix these problem)

Comment: I know `.find()` uses a loop. Why does that matter? He can do `var o = someArray.find(function(obj) { return obj.id == 5; }); console.log(o && o.coordinates);` Much simpler. But if you look at the desired result in the question, he *does* want an array. What he meant was that he doesn't want to have to write a separate array in code.

Comment: ...and you can drop `!obj || obj === null || obj === undefined || ` from `isEmpty()`. The `Array.isArray()` handles that. Or at least drop the `null` and `undefined` check, since `!obj` also handles it.

Comment: how can find `id` from `someArray`. it already edited to `[{latitude: 1212, longitude: 13324}, {latitude: 1314, longitude: 15151}] `. There isn't ID.

Comment: Helper(which I usually use from this in large project) includes  many methods. Also, `isEmpty` checks allmost all types. it isn't isEmptyArray(it is more common).

Comment: So, question is incorrectly, I think. it is not dynamically way(which he asks about returning same array). Also, he and you want short codes.

Comment: see that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32359183/4365315 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/32356779/4365315

Comment: The Array with the coordinates is showing the desired result. He doesn't want to find it by ID. That's not anywhere in the question. Not sure why you're pointing me to your SO question. The solution is still very over-engineered for the simple problem.

Comment: Thanks @squint. I just think to be dynamic. Sorry if i bother you. My answer doesn't deserve `-3`. Good luck

Comment: Doesn't bother me at all. Just letting you know that you're not answering the question being asked. Don't take it personally. You may love the code for your purposes but it doesn't have much relevance here. If you don't like the votes, delete your answer.

Comment: I have changed completely  my answer,  so just remove downvotes