# Which ways are best to define my method.

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

My methods are in Helper

```
var Helper = {
    isEmpty: function (obj) {
        return !obj || obj === null || obj === undefined || Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length === 0;
    },
    pushArray: function (arr1, arr2) {
        if (arr1 && arr2 && Array.isArray(arr1)) {
            arr1.push.apply(arr1, Array.isArray(arr2) ? arr2 : [arr2]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** So, if I have two functions that is `isEmpty`(it porposes to check from Array, String, Object) and `pushArray`, which of these following three methods should I use to define that functions?. And, What differences are there in three way?

There is three way(Maybe, there are other ways.):

Way 1:`Array.prototype.someMethod = function(){ ... }`

Way 2:`var Helper = {someMethod: function(){ ... }}`

Way 3:`window.someMethod = function(){ ... }`

Personally, I think that:

- Way1 is not recommended. Because, it's object of ES(ecmascript), not my. Maybe, your method will add by ES in future.
- Way2 is my way which I usually use this. It is global. Also depends it where you use
- Way3 is global way. Also, window is not my object. It doesn't recommend

Please, explain with details.(Also, i didn't find such question) Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Which to use depends upon your requirements and how you are going to use the function/method.  There are cases for each of the three depending upon needs.  So, basically this question does not contain enough info to answer in light of some specific context.

Comment: First of all, you need to decide on which type of object you want to create your method as in your list, the first object is an array, second a local variable and third a global object. I think your question is somehow vague

Comment: Please read [Function declaration, Function expression](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/) and [Prototype methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: Those answers don't really answer the question because there IS NO ANSWER to your generic question.  It depends entirely upon the situation and you have not described the situation.  There are times when it is appropriate to add a method to the Array prototype.  There are times when it is appropriate to define a new global function.  There are times when it is appropriate to put a method on an object.  Which to use depends upon the details of the circumstances and it is far too broad a question to ask us to explain all possible answer for all possible circumstances.

Comment: You could improve your question and describe a particular circumstance and then we could offer a very specific answer for that circumstance.  This is part of learning how to ask good, clear and specific questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: This question is like saying should I drive, walk, ride or fly to my destination?  Well, the answer is it depends upon a whole bunch of aspects of the situation like how far it is, how much time you have, whether you want to get exercise, how much money you can afford to spend, what neighborhood it is, your physical capabilities, etc...  Each possible answer is appropriate in some circumstances.

Comment: I would suggest that you propose a specific function and then ask in that context.  So, if I have a function that does X, which of these three methods should I use to define that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've proposed two functions that look like they are primarily designed to work with arrays, but they should return intelligent results if you pass them something other than an array.

So, right away, you can't use the `Array.prototype` method because if the data is not an array, that method won't exist on the object and you won't get the behavior you have currently coded.

So, it really comes down to whether they should be global functions or namespaced functions on your own global object.

When in doubt, fewer global symbols is generally the right answer because more global symbols make it more likely you may have a conflict with other code you might include in your project.

I would suggest this revised implementation of your namespace object:

```
var Helper = {
    isEmpty: function (obj) {
        return !obj || (Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length === 0);
    },
    pushArray: function (arr1, arr2) {
        if (Array.isArray(arr1)) {
            if (Array.isArray(arr2) {
               // push one array onto the end of the other
               arr1.push.apply(arr1, arr2);
            } else if (arr2 !== undefined) {
               // push a value onto the array
               arr1.push(arr2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `isEmpty()`, I've removed the `obj === null || obj === undefined` checks because they will never be hit because `!obj` will already catch those.

In `pushArray()`, I've made it so a falsey value passed in `arr2` (such as `0`) can be pushed into the array which your code would not allow.

Comment: Thanks. Good job.  If I use `Helper.pushArray(arr, null)` would be error. does `obj` equal to  `null` ||  `undefined`  || `""` or `false`(Did I forget any cases).

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev - my code tests to see if `arr2` was actually passed as an argument and if so, pushes into the array whatever was passed.  `null` is a valid value in the array just like `""` is so I assume that if the caller passes those, then that's what they wanted in the array.  If you want to exclude certain values from being pushed into the array, you will have to test for whichever specific values you want to exclude - not something I can know as it's your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Way1 is generally suggested not to use, as in future version's of ecmascript the same function may be introduced which will then be overridden.

Way3 is OK to use,but then you are creating a global object directly and as a good practice its good if we have minimum number of global variables.

I prefer u sing Way2 where we encapsulate the utility methods inside a single object for the whole application.Having a single entry point is a good practice,you can create hierarchy inside that . This allows you to have all the custom methods under single variable name and doesnot expose it directly on global namespace as individual one.

Comment: Tarang you understand my question correctly. Also, i know your suggestion. But, I doubt it. I want to know exact

Comment: So no method is a wrong one, its just about a good way or bad way to achieve a functionality.

Comment: All three methods of defining a function each have a place in good Javascript practice.  Which to use depends entirely upon the circumstance which the OP has not made specific so it's hard to make any single recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.someMethod = function() { ... }
```

This makes it so that *all* arrays now have `someMethod`. That means that if you have the following:

```
var someArray = [ 1, 2 ];
for (var i in someArray) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

It will print:

> 0
>
> 1
>
> someMethod

This is because, as mentioned earlier, the property `someMethod` has been added to *all* arrays, and now must be filtered out with `someArray.hasOwnProperty(i)`. See the [jsBin here](http://jsbin.com/zaloralujo/2/edit?js,console).

```
var Helper = { someMethod: function() { ... } };
```

This limits the scope of `someMethod` to be called with only `Helper.someMethod()`.

```
window.someMethod = function() { ... };
```

This makes the `someMethod` function global now. This can have unforeseen consequences if you or someone else overwrites the `someMethod` function, and can be hard to debug.